# How to pass host variables directly as a SQL variable value in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to write a SQL query for postgres using python in Jupyter where at different places, the code will be required to fetch different variable values extracted before in other code blocks. Is there a way to pass the variable values directly into SQL query. I know the '%s' route, but that way won't be able to specify which value should be referred when.
[Referral_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtqJO.png)
Like, in the third code block in the image, how to let the command know that the 'id' I'm talking about is in the variable named 'resourceFHIRID' in the second code block.

Comment: Please copy and paste the crs.execute and post here in text form.

Comment: csr.execute(insert,(resourceFHIRID, resource_type, from_instance, patientFHIRID, version_id, status, json.dumps(resource_content), load_ts))

Comment: Well you can't use ```WHERE``` in an ```INSERT``` unless you are using it to supply data to ```VALUES``` and you already  inserting 'resourceFHIRID' into what I presume is id. Are you sure you don't want ```UPDATE```. Personally I used named arguments to keep things straight and be self-documenting.

Comment: That was just a sample query I used to show what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for the added info though. :)